# Swift: GPUImage3 OverlayBlend with OpacityAdjustment doesn't behave like expected

Tags: swift, gpuimage

I try to add some noise overlay to an image with the following:

```
var picture = PictureInput(image:UIImage(named:"IMG_3331.jpg")!)
var blendImage = PictureInput(image:UIImage(named:"Noise.jpg")!)
let opacityFilter = OpacityAdjustment()
let blendFilter = OverlayBlend()

opacityFilter.opacity = mySlider.value

blendImage --> opacityFilter --> blendFilter
picture --> blendFilter --> renderView

blendImage.processImage()
```

When the opacityFilter.opacity is 0 then I see the Noise.jpg completely (expected that I don't see it at all), and when opacityFilter.opacity is 1 then I see the Noise.jpg only slightly as an overlay.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you create 1 image blend from IMG_3331 and Noise. After blend this image blended with IMG_3331 and adjuntment attribute mix of blend